# Need to find the way to slice this array to show only n customers

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

So , i basically want to show only 5 customer per page, i'll later add a pagination bar but at the moment i want to show only 5 customer, i have tried to slice after the map function, but im kinda new to react and redux and im not sure if that's the way.

```
const Setting = ({
    itemFromPage,
    BBDDCustomer
}) => {
   console.log({BBDDCustomer});
   const renderRows = BBDDCustomer.data.map((customer, customerIndex) => { //how to slice this array 
   return (
      <tr key={customerIndex}>
          <td>{BBDDCustomer.data[customerIndex].name}</td>
          <td>{BBDDCustomer.data[customerIndex].address}</td>
          <td>{BBDDCustomer.data[customerIndex].postalCode}</td>
          <td>{BBDDCustomer.data[customerIndex].city}</td>
          <td>{BBDDCustomer.data[customerIndex].country}</td>
          <td>{BBDDCustomer.data[customerIndex].telephone}</td>
          <td>{BBDDCustomer.data[customerIndex].email}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="customerIndex" value="mod"/></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="customerIndex" value="Del"/></td>
       </tr>
    );
 });
 return (
  <div>
    <Table>         
   </div>
  );
};
```

This is the format file where the customer are:

```
    const BBDDCustomer = {
          ui_labels: {
            name: 'Name',
            address: 'address',
            postalCode: 'Postal Code',
            city: 'City',
            country: 'Country',
            telephone: 'Telephone',
            email: 'Email',
            modified: 'Modified',
            delete: 'Delete'
          },
      data: [
        {
          name: 'n1',
          address: 'a1',
          postalCode: 'PC 1',
          city: 'c 1',
          country: 'cou 1',
          telephone: 'tel 1',
          email: 'em 1'
        }
    }
```

Comment: please, improve indentation of the displayed code. Remove useless code parts to present only the parts of code that produce your problem. Besides, last code part is just a js object, there is no jsx inside. jsx is your first code part. please improve your whole post. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to get a sub-array and render it than render the whole array and get a sub-array.

There is a standard Javascript `slice(from, count?)` method to get a part of array, first parameter tells the index to start with, second optional parameter is the number of elements to be included

You would use it like so:

```
const renderRows = BBDDCustomer.data.slice(0, 5).map((customer, customerIndex) => { ... };
```

It would return first 5 elements which you would map with your array function.